# li hover the whole line horizontally

Tags: css, hover, mouseover

I have a list with `li` elements and I want on mouseover, to hover the entire line separately.
In the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fnbTg/3/), I managed to hover but just the `<span>`. As I have 2 `<span>`s in the same line, there are two different hover areas.

How can I hover the whole line on mouseover?

Comment: `li:hover` instead of `span:hover`?

Comment: You mean this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/fnbTg/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your `span`s in another `span` and give it a `block` display. Apply `:hover` to this wrapping `span`:

*Example HTML:*

```
<li>
    <span class="hi">
        <span> f1.txt</span>
        <span class="pull-right">Size: 0.04 kb </span>
    </span>
</li>
```

*Example CSS:*

```
span.hi {
    display: block;
}

span.hi:hover {
    ...
}
```

**Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/fnbTg/4/**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
li:hover>:not(ul) {
    background: #E0F0FF;
}
```

This will color based on :hover on the li, not based on hover on the span. But on the other hand, you don't want to color the sublist, so use :not().

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QkaYJ/1/